# Как разбить servlet на несколько фрагментов с другими сервлетами?

Tags: java, servlet

У меня есть индек сервлет разбитый на две части меню, и разное содержание(сервлеты).
Как в индекс поместить меню и разное содержание? И реализовать их взаимодействие?

Comment: Может быть вы хотите разбить  jsp файл на несколько файлов? Или уточните конкретнее и добавьте пример кода, что и куда нужно включить.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы на одной странице отражалось несколько jsp файлов и они взаимодействовали между собой. Что-то типа устаревших фреймов в HTML. Показать нечего. У меня есть jsp но я не знаю как их склеить :(. Вычитал что это делают спомощю ajax но я в JS не в зуб ногой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот пример, попробуйте так: index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
     <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
     <jsp:include page="body.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да спасибо. Как раз к чему то такому пришел. Только еще в div запихнул :). А как из хедера на body воздействовать? Пока думаю...но совет не помешает :)

Comment: Ну хотя бы напишите каким образом воздействовать? Какой результат хотите получить?

Comment: Вообщем пока выкрутился так :  ` <form form action="body.jsp" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="success" value="success" />
  <input type="submit" name="index" value="index" />

</form>
<% if (request.getParameter("success") != null){
System.out.println(request.getParameter("success"));%>
<div class="block1"><jsp:include page="success.jsp"></jsp:include></div>
<%}%>

<% if (request.getParameter("index") != null){
  System.out.println(request.getParameter("index"));%>
<div class="block1"><jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include></div>
<%}%>`